# Getting file name with extension

Tags: c#, get, filenames

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2022 and am trying to get a file name out of a specific folder.

The path to the folder is "C:\Users\User\Pictures\Test" and there is just one .png file in it.

when I use the following code:

```cs
string path = Path.GetFileName(path:@"C:\Users\User\Pictures\Test\");

//result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

It just returns a blank line. I was expecting the file name.

I will eventually have a number of files in the folder and will want to obtain those too.

Comment: Why would you expect a file name if you clearly only provide a folder path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetFiles() not returning first file name in directory C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627235/getfiles-not-returning-first-file-name-in-directory-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

For read files in folders use this code:

```
var path = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\Pictures\Test");

foreach(var item in path)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Path.GetFileName()`method takes a string as an argument which is supposed to be a relative or full path to a **file**. It simply cuts the input string and returns only the file name. It does not read folders for you.

To read files of folders, refer to Felipe's answer. `Directory.GetFiles(path/to/folder)`will give you an array of (full) paths to the files in that folder. If you expect only a single file to be in a folder you can just use linq and combine the two methods like this:

`var filename = Path.GetFileName(Directory.GetFiles("path/to/folder").First());`

This will get you the filename of the first (or only) file in the folder "path/to/folder". If it could be empty you should of course handle that scenario too